# $f^{'}(z)$ exists if and only if $\dfrac{df}{d\overline{z}} =0$

Tags: complex-analysis

> $f^{'}(z)$ exists if and only if $$\dfrac{df}{d\overline{z}} =
>  \dfrac{df}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{d\overline{z}} +
>  \dfrac{df}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{d\overline{z}} =
>  \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{df}{dx}-\dfrac{1}{2i}\dfrac{df}{dy}=0$$

My professor briefly mentioned this in his notes, however, i tried to read up more on this but cannot find a convincing proof or the intuition behind this. Is it related to the Cauchy Riemann equations?

And if let's say there is a question as such: Is the function $f(z) = z + \overline{z}$ differentiable? Instead of using the Cauchy Riemann, i can use the above formula and say that since $\dfrac{df}{d\overline{z}} = 0 + 1 = 1 \neq 0$, it follows that $f$ is not differentiable anywhere? Here i treated $z$ as a constant?

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you separate the real and imaginary parts of $\frac{1}{2}\frac{df}{dx}-\frac{1}{2i}\frac{df}{dy}=0$ (remembering that $f = u+iv$, where $u$ and $v$ are real valued), you get exactly the CR equations.